# How to write the header from a .csv file to an array using powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

How do I read only the head from a CSV file and write the columnn names into an array?
I have found a solution using following cmdlets:

```
$obj = Import-Csv  '.\users.csv' -Delimiter ';'

$headerarray = ($obj | Get-member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name')
```

But the problem is the name - values are auto sorted alphabetic

Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the column names of a CSV file like this:

```
import-csv <csvfilename> |
  select-object -first 1 | foreach-object { $_.PSObject.Properties } |
  select-object -expandproperty Name
```

Comment: thankyou, i will try it. Working on this since 3 days, iam new to scripting

Comment: @Arturka1 to answer your question you could use `-delimiter` parameter of `Import-CSV`. Documentation would have helped with this one. Same as you did in your original post.